# Zip latest committed changes only

Tags: git, bash

Git has the very handy `archive` command which allows me to make a copy of a particular commit in a .zip archive like so:

```
git archive -o ../latest.zip some-commit
```

This will contain the entire working tree for that commit. Usually I just need the changed files since a previous release. Currently I use this to get those files into a zip:

```
git diff --name-only previous-commit latest-commit | zip ../changes.zip -@
```

This will however zip files from my working copy, which may have uncommitted changes. Is there some way to get only the changed files as they were committed directly into a zip?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`git archive` will accept paths as arguments. All you should need to do is:

```
git archive -o ../latest.zip some-commit $(git diff --name-only earlier-commit some-commit)
```

or if you have files with spaces (or other special characters) in them, use xargs:

```
git diff --name-only earlier-commit some-commit | xargs -d'\n' git archive -o ../latest.zip some-commit
```

If you don't have xargs properly installed, you could cook up an alternative:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n'
files=($(git diff --name-only earlier-commit some-commit))

git archive -o ../latest.zip some-commit "${files[@]}"
```

Written as a shell script, but should work as a one-liner too. Alternatively, change `earlier-commit`, `some-commit`, and `../latest.zip` to `$1` `$2` and `$3` and you've got yourself a reusable script.

Comment: Beware that extracting such an archive will not delete any files. This may cause hard to diagnose problems later on.

Comment: @jilles: Very true. This is why patches are great. @Marnix van Valen: You could perhaps just generate the patch then wrap it with a script (you could even use a heredoc to keep it all in one file) - then it'd be both usable and, well, correct.

Comment: What I usually do is include a list of all added and removed files with the release. The customer will then manually add or remove the files to/from source control on his end. 
@Jefromi Good idea. That would completely remove any human errors. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @Jefromi One problem with the second command; it doesn't work on windows. The xargs version that comes with the Windows git installer doesn't support the -d option. Nor does any of the other xargs builds for windows I could find. Any idea's for an alternative?

Comment: @Marnix van Valen: Then I'd do it within bash. See the answer.

Comment: There is a working solution for file names with spaces here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226009/git-how-to-create-archive-with-files-that-have-been-changed/7226334#comment12246899_7226334

Comment: @marnix-van-valen Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639415/create-archive-of-modified-files-in-git-via-batch-file

Comment: I get a "fatal: Not a valid object name" when executing `git archive -o ../../../stash.zip INDEX path/to/file/one path/to/file/two`

Answer (score 5):

If creating a patch is not an option, then how about something like this:

```
git stash
git checkout latest-commit
git diff --name-only previous-commit | zip ../changes.zip -@
git checkout master
git stash apply
```

NOTE: The `git stash` and `git stash apply` are only needed if you have working copy changes that have not been committed.

NOTE 2: `git checkout latest-commit` will put you on a detached head.  Be sure to `git checkout master` when you are done or you could wind up having problems with future commits.

Comment: @Marnix van Valen Then why not turn it into a simple script (or batch file)?  The problem is that you need to translate the list of file names into specific versions.  The only other way I could think of is to use `git show latest-commit:file`.  However, I was not able to come up with a one liner to do this.  It would look something like this: `git diff --name-only previous-commit | xargs -I file git show latest-commit:file` ... but here is the problem.  This prints the file (without its name) to STDOUT.  How can this be translated into the zip file?

Answer (score 3):

I have comme up with a solution, one line and quite simple:

```
zip archive.zip $(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r latest-commit)
```

You can as well use any other archiving method like tar with this method.

Answer (score 2):

In order to implement something useful to solve such a question for me, I've implemented a simple bash script. The script takes a revision hash and creates a tar.gz archive with all changed files including directory hierarchy. 
Anyone could use it or modify, I would be happy if it will help someone.

Just run script in the directory that is root for git repository and pass revision hash to the command line argumens.

[Link to the script on hithub](https://github.com/crible/do_delivery)

Comment: The example looks llike this:
#./do_delivery.sh -r a5ab48cdbb -n "vmeagt_delivery"
===> Archive filename: "vmeagt_delivery-20120430"
===> Revisions affected: "a5ab48cdbb-->HEAD"
===> Output path: "/Users/crible/Projects/ServerView_Agents/"
===> Git repository: "/Users/crible/Projects/ServerView_Agents/"
===> Creating tar.gz archive...
===> Done!

Comment: It is just the first version, that strongly need to be improved :)

Answer (score 0):

try this, generate a patch_*Ymd*.zip from last commit:

`git diff HEAD@{1} --name-only -z | xargs -0 git archive HEAD -o patch_$(date +'%Y%m%d').zip --`

Answer (score -1):

why not create a git patch which you can then apply to the other codebase?

```
$ git format-patch HEAD^..HEAD
```

Comment: Not everybody knows how to work with patch files I'm afraid. I use this to supply new releases to my customers. Unzipping an archive is something even non-developers can do. Applying a patch requires skills not all my customers have mastered (or even want to master).