# Git. How to create archive with files, that have been changed?

Tags: git

Keeping the file structure, like `git-archive`

Comment: yes. between two commits

Comment: Which commit's content should go into the files which make up the archive?

Comment: All files content, like command "git archive -o update.zip" does

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git archive` takes file paths as arguments, so you could do something like:

```
git diff --name-status commit1 commit2 | awk '{ if ($1 != "D") print $2 }' | xargs git archive -o output.zip HEAD
```

**UPDATE**

The following will work if your file names include spaces:

```
git diff --name-status commit1 commit2 | awk '{ if ($1 != "D") printf("\"%s\"\n", substr($0,3)) }' | xargs git archive -o output.zip HEAD --
```

Note: the content of the files included in the archive is what it is at HEAD. To use content from some other commit, just change `HEAD` at the end of this command to whatever you want it to be.

Comment: I've been fighting a losing battle trying to figure out how to make this work if some of the file names contain spaces. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Neville Try `git diff --name-status commit1 commit2 | awk '{ if ($1 != "D") printf("\"%s\"\n", substr($0,3)) }' | xargs git archive -o output.zip HEAD --`

Comment: Cool, but remember that this won't work if your filename includes a double quote or newline (for more, read http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/fixing-unix-linux-filenames.html)

Answer (score 2):

Here is command to archive changes between commit tagged *release* and *HEAD*, also works with filenames that includes spaces, quotes, double quotes, any special characters:

```
git diff --name-only -z --diff-filter=ACMRT release..HEAD | xargs -0 git archive -o update.tar.gz HEAD --
```

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy of @Charles Duffy
https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy

Thanks to @Viperet answer. Below is to insert a pause if you have a very long list files to be archived. Xargs will run the same command multiple time with split arguments hence it will always produce the archived zip with the last split arguments. To correct that, a quick workaround is to insert a pause in between.

Again, it's a courtesy from Charles Duffy. 
[XARGS Long Arguments and Pause Between Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53688284/xargs-long-arguments-and-pause-between-commands)

Updated command:

```
git diff --name-only -z --diff-filter=ACMRT release..HEAD | xargs -0 bash -c '"$@"; sleep 10' _ git archive -o update.tar.gz HEAD
```

Hope it helps others as well.

Thank you,

Hatjhie