# XARGS Long Arguments and Pause Between Commands

Tags: bash, git, xargs

Xargs will execute command more than once automatically if the command arguments are too long.

I am currently retrieving the revision differences in git and passing those arguments to git archive through xargs. It happens that the revision differences are long hence xargs automatically split the command into two times.

Because of that, git archive done twice for the same archive that leads to whatever being archived by the first command is wiped out by the second command.

Is there any way to let xargs pause between command or maybe notify xargs to archive into two different zip file?

Comment: `Xargs will execute command more than once automatically if the command arguments are too long` Can you give an example? `seq -s '' 9999 | xargs -t -- echo >/dev/null` works fine and executes a single echo. I can't find a way to replicate the "too long" argument for xargs.

Comment: Xargs has -s option. If it exceeded its value, it will be split by xargs by running multiple times on the same command with splitted arguments.

Comment: @KamilCuk Read the [man page for xargs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html), which describes exactly this behavior. It will do this even *without* the `-s` option described in @Hatjhie's comment.

Comment: @KamilCuk, it's impossible for xargs to *not* have this behavior in some form -- there's an OS-level limit on maximum command-line argument length (which environment variables also count against). Even if that's ~120kb, xargs gets its input off stdin, which can have a completely unbounded/infinite input length, so input length will exceed what can go on a single command line eventually. (Also, note that the limit is on total size of the collection of strings, so a bunch of very short strings like `1` `2` `3` ... will take longer to get there than, say, a list of long filenames).

Comment: @Hatjhie, ...it would be helpful to show the actual command you're trying to run so we can speak concretely rather than speculatively about how to modify it.

Comment: ...it may even be that (indeed, it *sounds overwhelmingly likely to me that*) xargs isn't the right tool for your job at all, but we can't suggest what to use instead if we can't see y our code.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, Thanks. It's very helpful. For more details on what I am trying to achieve is at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226009/git-how-to-create-archive-with-files-that-have-been-changed/53690625#53690625 Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have xargs run any command you like; that certainly can be a command that pauses or runs another trigger you define between invocations.

So, if you're currently running:

```
xargs -0 doSomethingWithFiles
```

...you can replace it with:

```
xargs -0 bash -c '"$@"; sleep 5' _ doSomethingWithFiles
```

Comment: Thanks Sir! This is what I am looking for!