# Create archive of modified files in GIT via batch file

Tags: windows, git, batch-file

I'm using this git command to create an archive of the files modified within a specific commit:

```
git archive -o update.zip HEAD $(git diff --name-only COMMITID^)
```

where COMMITID is the id of the commit I'm looking to archive.  This works fine from the command line but I would like to run it from a batch file.  Here are the contents of the batch file I'm using:

```
git archive -o update.zip HEAD $(git diff --name-only %1^^)
```

where %1 is the commit id being passed in via SourceTree.  The problem I'm having is that this command when run from a batch file returns the following error:

> error: unknown option `name-only'

I'm guessing there may be some character escaping issues going but I'm unable to find what is specifically breaking.

How would I write that git command so that it will work from a batch file?

UPDATE

I tried removing the --name-only option and received the following error when trying the batch script via SourceTree:

> fatal: path not found: $(git

Hopefully that helps narrow down what may be going on.

FURTHER UPDATE

Turns out my syntax was wrong for grabbing only the modified files from a specific commit but using msandiford's answer I came up with this batch file script that works perfectly:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set output=
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r %1^^') do ( set output=!output! "%%a" )
git archive -o update.zip HEAD %output%
endlocal
```

Comment: If you put an `echo` in front of your `git archive` command in your batch file, does it show you what you would expect it to?

Comment: Yes, it appears to be formatted correctly in the echo output.

Comment: Make sure there are no strange characters in your command. It has happened to me that I had "invisible" control caracters in commands...

Comment: I went through and verified no bad characters.

Comment: Is this a Windows `.bat` file, or a cygwin bash script?  I don't think you can use `$(foo)` to get the output of a command in a Windows `.bat` file - you need to use the bizarre and obscure `for /f "delims=" %%a in ('git diff --name-only %1^^') do set output=%%a`, and then use `%output%` in the subsequent command.  You should probably quote it as `"%output%"` too.

Comment: It is a Windows batch file.  Could you post an answer that uses that syntax?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you need a windows batch file, and not a bash script, here is a minimal batch file that may do what you want:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set output=
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('git diff --name-only %1^^') do ( set output=!output! "%%a" )
git archive -o update.zip HEAD %output%
endlocal
```

It works by collecting all lines of the output of the `git diff ...` command into an environment variable, and then using this to perform the `git archive ...` operation.

Documentation for the Windows `for` command is [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/bb490909.aspx), including the `/f` switch.  Documentation for the `setlocal` command is [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491001.aspx).

Comment: what could I do, if I have a larger set of files and I receive the error "The input line is too long. The syntax of the command is incorrect." ?